# Inverse of a polynomial function

Tags: functions, inverse

I want to find the inverse of $f(x)=\frac{3}{4}x^2-\frac{1}{4}x^3 $ when $0<x<2$.

According to wolfram the answer is [inverse](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%203/4%2ax%5E2-1/4%2ax%5E3%20)

I would like to know how can I find wolfram's inverse.

Comment: No I just thought that this was the formula

Comment: What you effectively want to do is to [solve the cubic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots) $x^3 - 3x^2 + 4y = 0$ for values of $y \in [0\ldots 2]$. The tricky bit is that the range of $x$ specified is precisely that range for which there are three real roots, so you have to select the correct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct formula is $$(f^{-1})'(y) = \dfrac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(y))}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer.My method is wrong how can I find the inverse